# Getting "Variable Importance" from rpart

Tags: r, rpart

I'm performing a tree analysis using rpart, and I need to access the values of "Variable importance" as shown when the rpart object is printed.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: `fit$variable.importance`

Answer (score 6):

@rawr indicated it in the comments, I'll just make it an answer:

You can extract the variable importance from a rpart object using:

`fit$variable.importance`

Answer (score 0):

Just adding details on @user7779's answer, you can also access the information you need in the following way:

```
library(rpart)
my.tree = rpart(y ~ X, data = dta, method = "anova") # I am assuming regression tree.
summary(my.tree)
```

In the output, among the first lines, you find variable importance. Notice though that here everything is rescaled, thus you will get the *relative* importance (i.e., numbers are going to sum up to one hundred).